# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown Provider : ServiceProvider

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this error when executing ionic serve, the supplier does not recognize me, and I add them in the index.html 
**service.js**

```
angular.module('starter').service('ProdutosService', ProdutosService); 

ProdutosService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

function ProdutosService($http, $q){
    return {
        lista: lista
    };

    function lista() {
        return $http.get('comprar/productos.json')
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.data.productos;
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            $q.reject();
        });
    } 
};
```

---

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('starter').controller('ComprarCtrl', ComprarCtrl);

ComprarCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'ProductosService'];

function ComprarCtrl($scope, ProductosService) {
    var vm = this;
    ProductosService.lista().then(function(productos) {
        console.log(productos);
        $scope.productos = productos;
        vm.productos = productos;

});
}
```

Comment: Typo: when you are defining the service you name it `ProdutosService` but when you reference it you use `ProductosService`.

Comment: thank you very much, I had been looking for the error for 2 hours, I have not slept much